# Why are all 4 .php functions displaying with submit?

Tags: php, html

Started playing with .php a couple weeks ago and found this problem in a book. I have 4 different buttons that will call different functions respectively but currently all 4 of my functions are called when I click individual buttons? Need a little help understanding this one. Everything is working fine except the call. With each button submit a different function should be called. I have the html separate from the php code. What I'm looking at is click a button and the function is called. Currently it is calling all functions at the same time.

HTML:

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_POST['Sequence1'])) {
    echo Sequence1(); }
    else if (isset($_POST['Sequence2'])) {
        echo Sequence2(); }
        else if (isset($_POST['Sequence3'])) {
            echo Sequence3(); }
            else if (isset($_POST['Sequence4'])) {
                echo Sequence4(); }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sequence Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="q2.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="q2_process.php" method="post">
<div class="header">
<header><h1>Numeric Sequence Tester</h1></header>
</div>
<div class="prompt">
<h2>Click on a button below to see the sequence</h2>
</div>
<div class="button1">
    <p><button type="submit" formmethod="post" name="Sequence1" value="Sequence1" class= "buttons">Sequence 10 - 2n</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="button2">
    <p><button type="submit" formmethod="post" name="Sequence2" value="Sequence2" class="buttons">Sequence 4n + 3</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="button3">
    <p><button type="submit" formmethod="post" name="Sequence3" value="Sequence3" class="buttons">Sequence n*n - 2</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="button4">
    <p><button type="submit" formmethod="post" name="Sequence4" value="Sequence4" class="buttons">Sequence ar^n; when a-4 r=3</button></p>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>

PHP Functions:

    <?php
function Sequence1() {
    $num = 0;
    $result = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $num++;
        $num1 = (2 * $num);
        $result = 10 - $num1;
        echo "When n=${num};   10-2n = 10-2x $num1 = 10 - $num1 = $result  <br>"; }} ?>
<?php function Sequence2() {
    $num = 0;
    $result = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $num++;
        $num1 = (4 * $num);
        $result = $num1 + 3;
        echo "When n=${num};    4n+3 = 4 x $num + 3 = $num1 + 3 = $result <br>"; }}; ?>

<?php function Sequence3() {
    $num = 0;
    $result = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $num++;
        $num1 = ($num* $num);
        $result = $num1 - 2;
        echo "When n=${num};    n*n-2 = $num x $num - 2 = $num1 - 2 = $result <br>"; }}; ?>

<?php function Sequence4() {
    $num = 0;
    $result = 0;    
    for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) { 
        $a = 3;
        $r = 2; 
        $num++;
        $num1 = $a * pow($r, $num -1);
        $result = $num1 * 2;
        echo "When n=${num};    $num1 x 2 = $result <br>"; }} ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sequence Tester</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="q2.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<header><h1>Sequence Tester</h1></header>
</div>
<!--Create divs to hold each button click-->
<div class="seq1">
<h3>You selected button 1</h3>
<p><?php echo Sequence1(); ?></p>
</div>

<div class="seq2">
<h3>You selected button 2</h3>
<p><?php echo Sequence2(); ?></p>
</div>

<div class="seq3">
<h3>You selected button 3</h3>
<p><?php Sequence3(); ?></p>
</div>
<div class="seq4">
<h3>You selected button 4</h3>
<p><?php Sequence4(); ?></p>
</div>

<div class="home">
<a href="q2_index.html">Back to Homepage</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling each function here:

```
<div class="seq1">
<h3>You selected button 1</h3>
<p><?php echo Sequence1(); ?></p>
</div>

<div class="seq2">
<h3>You selected button 2</h3>
<p><?php echo Sequence2(); ?></p>
</div>

<div class="seq3">
<h3>You selected button 3</h3>
<p><?php Sequence3(); ?></p>
</div>
<div class="seq4">
<h3>You selected button 4</h3>
<p><?php Sequence4(); ?></p>
</div>
```

And that's why it appears that all buttons are submitted.

**Edited to answer your second question as to why the function is being output on top of the DOM:**

The output on top of the DOM is coming because you are calling your php functions here:

```
if (!empty($_POST['Sequence1'])) {
    $v = "button 1";
    Sequence1(); }
else if (isset($_POST['Sequence2'])) {
    $v = "button 2";
    Sequence2();  }
else if (isset($_POST['Sequence3'])) {
    $v = "button 3";
    Sequence3(); }
else if (isset($_POST['Sequence4'])) {
    $v = "button 4";
    Sequence4(); ; }
```

Since each function is defined by you to 'echo' results instead of 'returning' them to a variable (see your function description), it is outputted near the top of the page when you call it in the if/else loop above.

**Edited** I made some changes to your function calls to 'return' the values instead and then display them in the correct div. Try this:

```
    <?php
$v = '';
$j = '';
if (!empty($_POST['Sequence1'])) {
    $v = "button 1";
    $j = Sequence1(); }
else if (isset($_POST['Sequence2'])) {
    $v = "button 2";
    $j = Sequence2();  }
else if (isset($_POST['Sequence3'])) {
    $v = "button 3";
    $j = Sequence3(); }
else if (isset($_POST['Sequence4'])) {
    $v = "button 4";
    $j = Sequence4(); }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sequence Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="q2.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="header">
        <header><h1>Numeric Sequence Tester</h1></header>
    </div>
    <div class="prompt">
        <h2>Click on a button below to see the sequence</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="button1">
        <p><button type="submit" formmethod="post" name="Sequence1" value="Sequence1" class= "buttons">Sequence 10 - 2n</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="button2">
        <p><button type="submit" formmethod="post" name="Sequence2" value="Sequence2" class="buttons">Sequence 4n + 3</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="button3">
        <p><button type="submit" formmethod="post" name="Sequence3" value="Sequence3" class="buttons">Sequence n*n - 2</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="button4">
        <p><button type="submit" formmethod="post" name="Sequence4" value="Sequence4" class="buttons">Sequence ar^n; when a-4 r=3</button></p>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>

PHP Functions:

<?php
function Sequence1()
{
    $output = "";
    $num = 0;
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $num++;
        $num1 = (2 * $num);
        $result = 10 - $num1;
        $output .= "When n=${num};   10-2n = 10-2x $num1 = 10 - $num1 = $result  <br>";
    }
    return $output;
}

function Sequence2()
{
    $output = "";
    $num = 0;
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $num++;
        $num1 = (4 * $num);
        $result = $num1 + 3;
        $output .= "When n=${num};    4n+3 = 4 x $num + 3 = $num1 + 3 = $result <br>";
    }
    return $output;
}

function Sequence3()
{
    $output = "";
    $num = 0;
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $num++;
        $num1 = ($num * $num);
        $result = $num1 - 2;
        $output .= "When n=${num};    n*n-2 = $num x $num - 2 = $num1 - 2 = $result <br>";
    }
    return $output;
}

function Sequence4() {
    $output = "";
    $num = 0;
    $result = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $a = 3;
        $r = 2;
        $num++;
        $num1 = $a * pow($r, $num -1);
        $result = $num1 * 2;
        $output .= "When n=${num};    $num1 x 2 = $result <br>";
    }
    return $output;
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sequence Tester</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="q2.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <header><h1>Sequence Tester</h1></header>
</div>
<!--Create divs to hold each button click-->
<div class="seq_result">
    <h3>You selected <?php echo $v; ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $j; ?></p>
</div>

<div class="home">
    <a href="q2_index.html">Back to Homepage</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It nearly worked flawlessly. The additional "containers" had to be removed. Only one container is required at each button click. The last piece of this is to figure out why the output is pushing into the header region of the DOM.

Comment: @allendks45 The functions were called right on top in your if / else loop. Please see my updated answer :)

Comment: Had to play with the .css to output the way I wanted. Your solution is solid, great work and thanks!